# selecting table per type?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a problem on selecting different table of user_details by their user_ID from account table,

---

**Account table**

```
+---------+------------+---------------+------------+
| user_ID | user_Name  | user_Password | user_Level |
+---------+------------+---------------+------------+
| 1       | student    | student       | 1          |
| 2       | instructor | instructor    | 2          |
| 3       | admin      | admin         | 3          |
+---------+------------+---------------+------------+
```

---

**Student_details**

```
+---------+----------+--------------+
| stud_ID | user_ID  | stud_details |
+---------+----------+--------------+
| 1       | 1        | student      |
| 2       | null     | student2     |
| 3       | null     | student3     |
+---------+----------+--------------+
```

---

**Instructor_details**

```
+---------+---------+--------------+
| inst_ID | user_ID | inst_details |
+---------+---------+--------------+
| 1       | null    | instructor   |
| 2       | 2       | instructor2  |
| 3       | null    | instructor3  |
+---------+---------+--------------+
```

and the **Admin_details** same as detail table from above..

heres my sample query:

```
SELECT 
ua.user_ID,
ul.level_Name,
ua.user_Name,
ua.user_status,
(CASE
    WHEN ua.level_ID = 1 THEN (SELECT * FROM `record_student_details` rsd WHERE rsd.user_ID = ua.user_ID)
    WHEN ua.level_ID = 2 THEN "2"
    WHEN ua.level_ID = 3 THEN "3"
    ELSE "error"
END) as ulvl FROM `user_accounts` ua
LEFT JOIN user_level ul ON ua.level_ID = ul.level_ID
```

the result i wanted is like this, if user_level is 1 the detail of user must came from student_details, then if user_level is 2 his detail will be instructor_details then, if user_level is 3 then detail from admin_details

```
+---------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
| user_ID | user_Name  | user_Password | user_Level | details            |
+---------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
| 1       | student    | student       | 1          | Student_details    |
| 2       | instructor | instructor    | 2          | Instructor_details |
| 3       | admin      | admin         | 3          | Admin_details      |
+---------+------------+---------------+------------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want something like this:

```
SELECT ua.user_ID, ul.level_Name, ua.user_Name, ua.user_status,
       COALESCE(stud_id, inst_id) as id,
       COALESCE(stud_details, inst_details) as details
FROM user_accounts ua LEFT JOIN
     user_level ul
     ON ua.level_ID = ul.level_ID LEFT JOIN
     student_details sd
     ON sd.user_ID = ua.user_ID AND ua.level_ID = 1 LEFT JOIN
     student_details sd
     ON id.user_ID = ua.user_ID AND ua.level_ID = 2
```